# How do I remove parentheses/brackets around a term in Word 2007 equation?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, equation-editor

Say for example I have `A = (B) + C`, I can't work out how to remove the parentheses/brackets around B without also deleting B. There's no way to select the brackets individually, as far as I can tell...

Answer (score 9):

That behavior of Equation Editor is by design, and there is no way to delete B without deleting the parentheses. The program evaluates the parentheses as a whole object: `(◻)`

What you can do is (especially when the content in the parenthesis are longer) to double-click on the content to select it, and to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to cut it to be pasted later.

Answer (score 4):

Found another "solution" (which I don't like much more than copy/paste): switch to Line mode, where you *can* remove parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to cut and paste B outside the brackets, and then delete the brackets.